# Getting value of setCustomValidity in Jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, textarea

I have React component (crucial parts):

Declaration of ref:

```
private JsonInputRef: React.RefObject<HTMLTextAreaElement> = React.createRef();
```

Setup of ref:

```
this.JsonInputRef.current.setCustomValidity(errorMessage);
```

`render` function:

```
render() {
const { height = '', onValueChange, ...restProps } = this.props;
return (
  <StyledTextArea
    ref={this.JsonInputRef}
    {...restProps}
    onChange={this.handleValueChange}
    height={height}
  />
);
}
```

How I want to test it:

```
  it('componentDidUpdate should mount and change props', () => {
    const onChange = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = enzyme
      .mount(
        <JsonInput
          onChange={onChange}
          onValueChange={mockOnValueChange}
          value={exampleJsonStringValidated}
        />,
        { wrappingComponent: withTestThemeWrapper },
      );
    console.log('test', wrapper.ref('JsonInputRef'));
    expect(wrapper.ref('JsonInputRef').hasClass('valid'));
  });
```

And my issue is getting value which was passed by `setCustomValidity`, I thought that it should be something like `getCustomValidity` but probably I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use `validationMessage`